# In Akka, can I hold an ActorRef in an instance field?

Tags: akka

If I have an actor that sends messages to another actor, should I be obtaining a reference to that actor (e.g. `context.actorSelection(somePath)`) every time I want to send a message to it or can I do it once when my actor is initialized and then reuse the `ActorRef`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a distinction needs to be made between an actor failing and being restarted by it's supervisor and an actor being explicitly stopped.  If you had an `ActorRef` that you had obtained in some way or another (looked it up and resolved it via `ActorSelection` or just happened to have it from when it was created) and the underlying actor instance fails and is restarted by its supervisor, then that `ActorRef` will still work just fine.  Even though the actor technically stops during the fail and restart (`postStop` will be called), it's name is never released and any refs that referred to it will still be valid.

Now, if you explicitly stopped that actor, and then later started up a new one with the same name (and thus same path), `ActorRef`s that referred to it pre stoping **will not work**.  The actor instance that they referred to was stopped and thus these refs are invalid even though later a new instance was started with the same name and thus same path.

Lastly, you can use `ActorSelection`s to get around the issue described in the above paragraph.  If you keep the result of `.actorSelection` as an `ActorSelection` and do not resolve it into a single `ActorRef`, then you will continue to be able to send messages through it (`ActorSelection` supports tell/`!`) and to an actor represented by it even if the first instance is initially stopped and a new instance for the same name is started later.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse ActorRefs, that's what they're meant for.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/general/addressing.html

Comment: There are some things in that documentation that make me doubt the reusability of ActorRefs. "When an actor is terminated, its reference will point to the dead letter mailbox". "An actor reference designates a single actor and the life-cycle of the reference matches that actor’s life-cycle". So if an Actor dies, it sounds like the ActorRef is no good to me. If I was calling actorSelection every time, would Akka ensure that I always get a reference to a live actor?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee at all with an actor selection that there is any actor at the path you request.

Comment: I didn't word my question very well. If I have an ActorRef to an Actor that has died, I'm guessing that ActorRef is no good to me any more based on the reference documentation you linked to. Or does Akka somehow ensure that a new instance of the Actor is created transparently and I can continue to use the ActorRef?